# Create web.xml automatically in build.xml

Tags: jsp, ant

is there a way to create `web.xml` file using `ANT` `build.xml` file ?

I know i can do it using `org.apache.jasper.JspC`, but for some reason i'm getting `web.xml` with **only** root nodes...

Thanks

Comment: The web.xml is supposed to list the components of your webapp and their mapping. It's not something that can be automatically generated. If it was, what would be the point of this file? For example, how would the build.xml file guess that you want to map a servlet com.foo.bar.SomeServlet to /admin/hello.action?

Comment: however you can use xdoclet from the same as per this link http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/ant/xdoclet/modules/web/WebDocletTask.html

Comment: Is it possible to create this file based on existing servlet ?

Comment: Lrrr. As was said by JB Nizet, the point of this file is to define the servlet you really use and their configuration, as well as the organization of your whole web application. You shouldn't build it automatically.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for info guys. I needed to be sure that i did not omitted anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding mapping to `web.xml` file is possible using `org.apache.jasper.JspC` class. There is also possibility to create `web.xml` file using same class.